# use maven to build struts project in eclipse,i got something wrong

Tags: struts2

getting started in struts in eclipse,i use maven struts2-archetype-blank.when i run mvn test,there're bugs as following:

```
testHelloWorld(cn.jx.hw.learn.example.HelloWorldTest)  Time elapsed: 0.135 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport.getLocale(ActionSupport.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProviderSupport.getLocale(TextProviderSupport.java:329)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProviderSupport.getText(TextProviderSupport.java:204)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProviderSupport.getText(TextProviderSupport.java:119)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport.getText(ActionSupport.java:86)
    at cn.jx.hw.learn.example.HelloWorld.execute(HelloWorld.java:30)
```

Answer (score 0):

after comparing HelloworldTest.java with struts-example in github,i change

HelloWorld hello_world = new HelloWorld();
into
container.inject(HelloWorld.class);
and things go right. mvn test don't post bug